# Create a model based on a query instead of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As a first approximation, I would like to know if it would work to define a rails model based on a database view instead of a real table.

Of course, I want to use that model only to query and not to insert or update.

If that's possible, is it necessary to define the view? Can I instead specify somehow a query (so I do not need to actually create the view).

Comment: can you please show an example of what a query would look like for a model based on a database view vs the query based on the table? I'm not understanding the simplification (or other "improvement"?) that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the view already exists and the `database.yml` configuration is set correctly (i.e. the view is somehow inside the database you defined there) and its name is `View`.

The model:

```rb
# view.rb
def View < ApplicationRecord
   self.primary_key = 'id'
end
```

Then you can query like:

```
View.where(column_name: 'value')
```